# Figure of merit of Operational amplifier

Tags: analog, integrated-circuit, circuit-design, operational-amplifier

How can I measure FOM(figure of merit) of an operational amplifier? There are so many parameters, how can I decide which formula to use while calculating FOM?

Comment: Nobody does this. There is no generalized short cut to comparison of op-amps. So much (circuit performance) also depends on the components around them and the power supplies too.

Comment: What is the definition of the FOM? Calculating will not be a problem as soon you know its definition.

Comment: Figure of merit sounds like a sham that only a marketing team would come up with.

Comment: Just to pile it on: there is no one figure of merit for an op-amp.  If there were, there would be a couple of dozen op-amp designs on the market and nothing more.  **No** op-amp is perfect for **any** job, and each job demands different characteristics from an op-amp.  That's why there's so very many different op-amps in production.

Comment: Actually the RedRag (Journal of Solid State Circuits) encourages their authors to use FOM(s) in many ways, in many circuits, so the readers can more easily compare "This is yet another opamp topology used in yet another IF_channel_select filter for a CDMA radio" against other opamps used in such IF_filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Figure of Merit severely depends on the situation. In commercial applications I can only see limited use for it, but for R&D purposes it does have its advantages.

The idea is that you try to isolate anything that is not dependent on factors common to all amplifiers. For example, in CMOS design, driving a 1pF capacitive load can be made faster much easier than a 10pF capacitive load. It makes sense to have a FOM in this case that does not depend on the output capacitance.

The most commonly adopted FOM's that I have seen are something along the lines of

$$FOM = \frac{GBW\cdot C_L}{P}$$
or
$$FOM = \frac{GBW\cdot C_L}{I_{BIAS}}$$

But depending on the situation, other factors can be included as well. To find the FOM, you measure all the parameters in the equation and calculate the FOM manually.

Answer (score 2):

First, you define what your Figure of Merit (FOM) means.

I've sometimes (but not often) done this when comparing op-amps for a new application. Once I needed to make a low distortion video driver into 50 ohms, and had the choice of one beefy opamp, or several smaller ones in parallel. I defined an FOM as the output current / supply current for a given amplitude and distortion. I eventually used 3 in parallel.

Usually, FOM is only a good measure when you expect two parameters to scale with each other, and you have some freedom about where to operate (like how many opamps in parallel). For instance, if you were building synthesiser, you could use a 10MHz reference, or a 20MHz reference, with different multiplication ratios. Low noise oscillators have an FOM of phase noise / operating frequency, so it makes sense to pick the best ratio, and design the multiplication chain starting from there.

However, most opamp specifications do not scale, a ratio is not appropriate. You might need a particular bandwidth, or input impedance, or input offset. There the choice comes down to listing all the opamps that meet or exceed all of your specifications, and choosing the cheapest supplier that you trust. It does not make sense to define an FOM as (say) bandwidth per dollar, if your application requires a particular bandwidth.

An FOM of bandwidth per dollar could be useful in the marketing department as a way of showing you make better opamps than the competition.